# Redirect http to https but exclude some

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I'm using nginx and I want to know if it's possible to do this.

Now to manage my vhost, I create them separately in /etc/nginx/sites-available (activate them after)

```
mydomain.com
subdomain.mydomain.com
subdomain1.mydomain.com
anotherdomain.com
```

So to redirect http to https I create a redirect vhost, that contain :

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

mydomain.com and all other subdomain are under https.

But the problem is anotherdomain.com, I don't want to redirect it to https. And here I don't know how to do this. I've got an idea :

Create only on vhost, that contain all the config, and do this :

```
# Config of anotherdomain.com

# Redirect all domain/subdomain after this part to https
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# Config of mydomain.com
# Config of subdomain.com
# Config of subdomain1.com
```

This will work as a kind of override, like in CSS ?

Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you will have one forwarding block for each domain / subdomain. Redirection using the default_server isn't something I've seen done before, though in most cases it's probably ok.

So instead of using default server you define a block as follows, either for just the domain in question or for each domain

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name anotherdomain.com;

  location / {
    // whatever
  }
}
```

This will override the default_server block. Personally I'd define forwarding blocks for each website by domain, just because it seems neater.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`default_server` is the virtual host used when the request does not match any other virtual host.

So, therefore you need to define a virtual host that matches `anotherdomain.com` on port 80. nginx will then use that configuration instead of your `default_server` virtual host.